# Contando supervisores em pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin, plpgsql, pgadmin3

Como eu posso listar o nome de cada supervisor com a quantidade de supervisionados.

```
select f.NomeFunc, s.ID_Superv 
from Funcionario f 
inner join Funcionario s
on s.ID_Superv = f.ID_Func
having COUNT(f.NomeFunc);
```

Estou tentando assim mas ta dando erro.

Comment: Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 1):

Para obter o número de funcionários ligados a um supervisor podes utilizar o seguinte código. Utilizando o count para contar o número de funcionários no select e agrupar por nome de supervisor.

```
SELECT f.NomeFunc, count(s.ID_Superv)
  FROM  Funcionario f 
    INNER JOIN Funcionario s ON s.ID_Superv = f.ID_Func
GROUP BY f.NomeFunc
ORDER BY f.NomeFunc
```

O having pode ser utlizado quando quiseres filtrar o valor do resultado do count. Exemplo, caso queira verificar todos os supervisores que possuem mais de dois funcionários ligados a ele podes utilizar o seguinte código:

```
SELECT f.NomeFunc, count(s.ID_Superv)
  FROM  Funcionario f 
    INNER JOIN Funcionario s ON s.ID_Superv = f.ID_Func
GROUP BY f.NomeFunc
HAVING(count(s.ID_Superv) > 2)
ORDER BY f.NomeFunc;
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado